# How to make WP_Query not to show irrelevant posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, query-posts

I'm using the following `WP_Query` arguments array:

```
$args = array(  'post_type' => POST_TYPE,
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                'taxonomy' => TAX,
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => TERM
                            ),
                            'posts_per_page' => 2
                        );
```

The problem is this query displays all the posts from `POST_TYPE` which have a `TAX` (any `TAX`) assigned to them but it's not limiting it to the `TERM` (particularly one term) taxonomy!
I just want the posts from the specific `TERM` taxonomy and nothing more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're one array short. The tax_query is an array of arrays.

```
$args = array(  'post_type' => POST_TYPE,
                'tax_query' => array( 
                     array (
                      'taxonomy' => TAX,
                      'field' => 'slug',
                      'terms' => TERM
                     ), 
                 ),
                'posts_per_page' => 2
             );
```

See http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/ for more.

Comment: Thanks Otto, I didn't know it MUST be an array of arrays. You helped me a lot here.